# flutter fatal error: lipo: -extract armv7 specified but ... shared_preferences does not contain that architecture

Tags: flutter

I am building a Flutter app.

When I run app on iOS simulator, it's running fine.

And when I run it on Android Device, it's running fine.

But when I run it on iPhone device, there is error like below.

---

$ flutter run

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone11MaxPro in debug mode...

Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode 
 project: AX352BQR6K

Running Xcode build...

├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           6.7s

└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         2.9s

Xcode build done.                                           11.4s

Failed to build iOS app

Error output from Xcode build:

↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    fatal error: lipo: -extract armv7 specified but fat file:
    /Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo_dart_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/shared_preferences.framework/shared_preferences does not contain that architecture

Failed to extract armv7 for
    /Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo_dart_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/shared_preferences.framework/shared_preferences. Running lipo -info:
    Architectures in the fat file:
    /Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo_dart_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/shared_preferences.framework/shared_preferences are: arm64
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

note: Using new build system

note: Planning build

note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone11MaxPro.

---

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try changing workspace settings to Legacy Build Settings and try once again